# Java sorting: random gen numbers same as sorted numbers(in terms of order)

Tags: java, sorting, random

I have a program that sorts randomly generated numbers from least to greatest or greatest to least depending on the users choice. 2 problems are occurring.

When the user does Insertion Sorting with Descending, the randomly generated numbers and sorting numbers output like this for example:

Randomly Generated Numbers:
89 90 2 830 399

---

After sorting using the Insertion Sort, Using Descending Order, the array is: 
89 90 2 830 399

It's weird because my other methods are EXACTLY the same, and they work fine, but for some reason this doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;


public class RoutineSorter {

private static int[] generateRandomArray(int size, int randomMax) {
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomMax);
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MethodChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What method would you like to use to sort the random numbers" + "\n" + "1 - Selection Sort" + "\n" + "2 - Bubble Sort" + "\n" + "3 - Insertion Sort" + "\n" + "4 - Quick Sort"));
    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));
    int SortOrder = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1 - Ascending, " + "2 - Descending"));

    int[] array = generateRandomArray(iTotalCount, 1001);

    System.out.println("Randomly Generated number list: ");
    for (int i: array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");


    if (MethodChoice == 1) {
        if (SortOrder == 2) {
            selectionSortReverse(array);
            System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + " " + "the array is: ");
        } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
            selectionSort(array);


            System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort," + " the array is:");
        }
    } else if (MethodChoice == 2) {
        if (SortOrder == 2) {
            bubbleSortReverse(array);
            System.out.println("After sorting using the Bubble Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + " " + "the array is: ");
        } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
            bubbleSort(array);


            System.out.println("After sorting using the Bubble Sort," + " the array is:");
        }
    } else if (MethodChoice == 3) {
        if (SortOrder == 2) {
            insertionSortReverse(array);
            System.out.println("After sorting using the Insertion Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + " " + "the array is: ");
        } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
            insertionSort(array);


            System.out.println("After sorting using the Insertion Sort," + " the array is:");

        } else if (MethodChoice == 4) {
            if (SortOrder == 2) {

            }

        }

        for (int i: array) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

    }

}


public static void quickSort(int data[], int low, int high) {
    int partitionLoc;
    if (low < high) {
        partitionLoc = partition(data, low, high);
        quickSort(data, low, partitionLoc - 1);
        quickSort(data, partitionLoc + 1, high);
    }
}

public static void quickSortReverse(int data[], int low, int high) {
    int partitionLoc;
    if (low > high) {
        partitionLoc = partition(data, low, high);
        quickSort(data, low, partitionLoc - 1);
        quickSort(data, partitionLoc + 1, high);
    }
}

public static int partition(int data2[], int left, int right) {
    boolean moveLeft = true;
    int separator = data2[left];

    while (left < right) {
        if (moveLeft == true) {
            while ((data2[right] >= separator) && (left < right)) {
                right--;
            }
            data2[left] = data2[right];
            moveLeft = false;
        } else {
            while ((data2[left] <= separator) && (left < right)) {
                left++;
            }
            data2[right] = data2[left];
            moveLeft = true;
        }
    }
    data2[left] = separator;
    return left;
}



public static void bubbleSort(int data[]) {
    //Loop to control number of passes
    for (int pass = 1; pass < data.length; pass++) {
        //Loop to control # of comparisons for length of array-1
        for (int element = 0; element < data.length - 1; element++) {
            //compare side-by-side elements and swap them if
            //first element is greater than second element
            if (data[element] > data[element + 1]) {
                swap(data, element, element + 1); //call swap method
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void bubbleSortReverse(int data[]) {
    //Loop to control number of passes
    for (int pass = 1; pass < data.length; pass++) {
        //Loop to control # of comparisons for length of array-1
        for (int element = 0; element < data.length - 1; element++) {
            //compare side-by-side elements and swap them if
            //first element is greater than second element
            if (data[element] < data[element + 1]) {
                swap(data, element, element + 1); //call swap method
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void swapBubble(int array2[], int first, int second) {
    int hold = array2[first];
    array2[first] = array2[second];
    array2[second] = hold;

}


public static void insertionSort(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
        insert = data[next];
        int moveItem = next;

        while (moveItem > 0 && data[moveItem - 1] > insert) {
            data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
            moveItem--;
        }
        data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
}

public static void insertionSortReverse(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
        insert = data[next];
        int moveItem = next;

        while (moveItem < 0 && data[moveItem - 1] < insert) {
            data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
            moveItem--;
        }
        data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
}



public static void selectionSort(int data[]) {
    int smallest;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        smallest = i;
        //see if there is a smaller number further in the array
        for (int index = i + 1; index < data.length; index++) {
            if (data[index] < data[smallest]) {
                swap(data, smallest, index);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void selectionSortReverse(int data[]) {
    int smallest;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        smallest = i;
        //see if there is a smaller number further in the array
        for (int index = i + 1; index < data.length; index++) {
            if (data[index] > data[smallest]) {
                swap(data, smallest, index);
            }
        }
    }
}




public static void swap(int array2[], int first, int second) {
    int hold = array2[first];
    array2[first] = array2[second];
    array2[second] = hold;



}
```

}

Comment: If `insertionSort(int data[])` works fine you can just print the array in reverse order. No need to have two functions doing practically the same thing.

Comment: @Linus, I'd like to have all of the code be consistent. Using ascending mode, the code is fine, but when I go to do it in descending, that's when it prints the numbers in the same order.

Comment: `moveItem` is *never* initialized to less than `0`, so your while-loop is never entered.  You should really learn to use a debugger, since this sort of mistake is immediately obvious once you start stepping through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method insertionSortReverse() there is the mistake at the beginning of the while loop:

```
while (moveItem < 0 &&
```

It should be

```
while (moveItem > 0 &&
```

I suppose...

Comment: We both posted our answer at the same time :) I just realized it! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The problem was my `insertionSortReverse()` subroutine, one of the signs was the wrong way, so I put it to the opposite.

**BEFORE**

```
public static void insertionSortReverse(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
      insert = data[next];
      int moveItem = next;

      while (moveItem < 0 && data[moveItem - 1] < insert) {
        data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
        moveItem--;
      }
      data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
  }
```

**AFTER**

```
public static void insertionSortReverse(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
      insert = data[next];
      int moveItem = next;

      while (moveItem > 0 && data[moveItem - 1] < insert) {
        data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
        moveItem--;
      }
      data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
  }
```